# BABE: VRF verification fails

Tags: consensus, babe

We just ran into the following issue on our kintsugi testnet deployment:

```
[Relaychain] :broken_heart: Verification failed for block 0xdef612b6bd9d3b6a2ff93a1e9310f385b7a8b715f3f368135731772a3c6f0792 received from peer: 12D3KooWEG2yLqePwnfa6s3CycUuqkzCC4LdG63Ke8qfrfhj7jPi, "VRF verification failed: EquationFalse"
```

We are using a self-hosted rococo relay chain with v0.9.37 and we are on interbtc release 1.21.8 (polkadot v0.9.36).

I saw that the issue is already reported in [GitHub issue #12752](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/12752) and fixed in https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13135.

However, is there a way to recover the testnet from this issue? We are currently running a competition on that testnet so resetting the testnet (what we might normally do) is not our preferred option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely, this issue won't be coming up again as all teams will be at polkadot v0.937 or greater by the time I wrote this answer, but still happy to share how we resolved the issue.

1. Upgrade the parachain polkadot dependencies to v0.9.37 (or greater)
2. Start a new parachain node with relaychain part set to `--execution=native-else-wasm` (on polkadot 0.9.37)
3. New node is syncing to latest blocks
4. Reset existing collator nodes one by one (all on 0.9.37) and they sync/produce blocks again